# Android fade out animation for tablerow

Tags: android, animation, invisible, fadein, fadeout

I have a `TableRow` with a `TextView`. Here is the xml for it.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#BF000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:background="#BF000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/text_searchword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </TextView>

</TableRow>
```

I want to make the table row invisible with fadeout effect on a button touch and vice versa. How can I do it?

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any `View` (`TableRow` included) can have a fade animation attached to it, but you'll need to be able to reference your view in code, so the row will need an id:

```
<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/my_row"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:background="#BF000000">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/topText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:background="#BF000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/text_searchword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  </TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Now you can reference the row itself in your Java code somewhere (like `onCreate()` perhaps) as

```
View row = findViewById(R.id.my_row);
```

Notice I don't cast it as a `TableRow`.  You could if you need to do other things with it, but for just setting visibility leaving it as a View is fine.  Then just construct a button click method like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    View row = findViewById(R.id.myrow);
    if(row.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        row.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
        row.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        row.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
        row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Fade in and Fade out are standard animations defined in the Android package, you don't need to create them yourself, just load them using `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()`.  In this example, the clicking the same button just toggles between fade in and fade out depending on whether or not the View is already visible.

Hope that Helps!